# beamer: shading the block environment

Tags: beamer, color, shading

I want the `block` environment to be shaded in blue, because now it is hardly noticeable. The LaTeX code I'm using is

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{%
\usetheme[hideothersubsections,
right,width=22mm]{Goettingen}
 }
\title{Math}
\author[Mister X]{X}
\institute{University}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{USTL}}
\date{January 15, 2012}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
 The following proposition is easy to prove.
\begin{block}{Proposition}
 some statement
 \end{block}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\titlegraphic` command is not needed in your example and, even more important, will prevent successful compilation for people who don't have access to your "USTL" graphic file.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Consider to use the `rose` color theme in addition to the `Goettingen` theme -- this way, the `block` environment will feature light blue colors which go together well with the sidebar colors.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<beamer>{%
\usetheme[hideothersubsections,right,width=22mm]{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{rose}
}

\title{Math}
\author[Mister X]{X}
\institute{University}
% \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=20mm]{USTL}}
\date{January 15, 2012}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<handout:0>
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
The following proposition is easy to prove.
\begin{block}{Proposition}
some statement
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]